# Use Jade as Durandal View Engine?

Tags: pug, durandal

Durandal looks like it supports custom view engines:
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Engine/

But am having a hard time understanding what to change or add to use Jade templates as my Durandal view engine (client-side, not rendered on server)

Should one do a full rewrite of the viewEngine.js implementation in the Durandal source? (https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/App/durandal/viewEngine.js)

Or is there a simpler approach such as adding jade as a requirejs loader?
(for example https://github.com/rocketlabsdev/require-jade)

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I did try to add the above requirejs plugin to Durandal, and configure via main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    ...
    'jade': 'durandal/amd/jade'
  }
});

...

var viewEngine = require('durandal/viewEngine');
viewEngine.viewExtension = ''; // Using .jade here results in requests for SomeView.jade.jade
viewEngine.viewPlugin = 'jade';
```

But the view locator seems to have troubles and not sure how to configure with this setup.  Note, I am using the convention of views (.html) and viewmodels (.js) being side-by-side in the same directory, which works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By slightly modifying the `viewEngine` you can make it load and render `.jade` files. Monkey patching the requirejs path config to the default `viewEngine` allows Durandal to load a different view engine.

I've slapped something together [here](https://github.com/jpwesselink/durandal-jade), demo can be found [here](http://jpwesselink.github.io/durandal-jade)

Hope this helps you in the right direction.